# Multilingual characters in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridView built using asp.net.  I have a text box in the grid view which accepts user input.
When the user gives any multilingual character for example "您好" , it is stored as "???"
How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In database table change the column datatype to nvarchar. this works for me to store text of different languages.